# Excel: How to automatically update sum formula when a column is added while keeping the same range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am currently having a problem in Excel.
I am trying to find a sum of yearly cost, and this excel sheet will be updated as the month goes on.
The problem is, I could easily sum the yearly cost using the sum function, but I would like it to happen that when a new column (month) and cost is updated in that column, i still want to calculate the yearly cost.

So for example, a yearly cost would right now would be the sum from June 2022 to July 2021. and next month, it would be June 2022 to August 2022. I have seen the sum(indirect) function, but this doesn't seem to include the fact that I have to remove the begininning column from my formula when a new column is added.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm a little confused:
1. "So for example, a yearly cost would right now would be the sum from June 2022 to July 2021. "
Should this say to July 2022?
2. "but this doesn't seem to include the fact that I have to remove the begininning column from my formula when a new column is added"
But the example you gave doesn't involve removing the beginning column.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I want a sum to include columns I insert later, I do this by having an empty column between the individual columns to be summed and the sum column, and including this empty column in the SUM range.  Then when I insert a column to the left of the empty column, the SUM function will include the cell in this new column, since it is inside the range.

However, a more versatile approach, which also eliminates the need for this empty column, is to use a formula like:

```
=SUM(A1:OFFSET(K1,0,-1))
```

This example is to enter into cell K1 to sum the range from A1 to J1.  The `OFFSET` function works on the cell reference rather than the value in the cell.  `OFFSET(cell, y, x)` means the cell `y` rows below and `x` columns to the right of `cell`.

If you want the start of the sum range to roll forward, you can use the OFFSET function for this likewise.  For example

```
=SUM(OFFSET(K1,0,-6):OFFSET(K1,0,-1))
```

would give you the most recent six columns.  I'm confused as to what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

A formula like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(A2,0,COUNTA(2A:ZZ2)-3))&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET(A2,0,COUNTA(A2:ZZ2)-1))))
```

will first count the number of cells with values in A2:ZZ2
*(due to `COUNTA(A2:ZZ2)` by that also forcing the first OFFSET() parameter to be A2*

`CELL("address",OFFSET(A2,0,COUNTA(A2:ZZ2)-3))` will create a string with the address of the cell **TWO** columns left of the last cell (with value) in the range. *(The `-3` is `-1` in the second OFFSET() to make it find the last value)*

... and that will make the text formed by the  `CELL(...) & ":" & CELL(...)` create a cell-range corresponding to the last 3 cells on that row.

`INDIRECT()` then 'interprets' that cell-range-text, and hands it over to `SUM(...)`, which then can do the calculation.

Note: to get a FULL row -range; use e.g. `COUNTA(2:2)` for the second row.

*Verified in LibreOffice, should work in any SpreadSheet version.

Many INDIRECT() function calls may render your spreadsheet slow*